# Extract value of pandas dataframe with differents index columns according to the rows

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have this dataframe with **1 000 000 rows** and 1**00 columns**.

```
   0       1          2         3         4         5         6          ...
0  2.645751  2.828427  3.000000  3.000000  3.000000  3.000000  3.000000   
1  2.645751  2.828427  2.828427  3.000000  3.000000  3.000000  3.000000   
2  2.449490  2.449490  2.645751  2.645751  2.645751  2.645751  2.645751   
3  2.000000  2.236068  2.449490  2.449490  2.449490  2.449490  2.449490   
4  2.449490  2.828427  2.828427  2.828427  2.828427  2.828427  2.828427   
5  1.414214  1.414214  1.414214  1.414214  1.414214  1.414214  1.732051
```

***Reproductible example (convert it to df) :***

```
df={0: {0: 2.6457513110645907, 1: 2.6457513110645907},
 1: {0: 2.8284271247461903, 1: 2.8284271247461903},
 2: {0: 3.0, 1: 2.8284271247461903},
 3: {0: 3.0, 1: 3.0},
 4: {0: 3.0, 1: 3.0},
 5: {0: 3.0, 1: 3.0},
 6: {0: 3.0, 1: 3.0},
 7: {0: 3.0, 1: 3.0},
 8: {0: 3.0, 1: 3.0},
 9: {0: 3.0, 1: 3.0},
 10: {0: 3.0, 1: 3.0},
 11: {0: 3.0, 1: 3.0},
 12: {0: 3.0, 1: 3.0},
 13: {0: 3.0, 1: 3.0},
 14: {0: 3.0, 1: 3.0},
 15: {0: 3.0, 1: 3.0},
 16: {0: 3.0, 1: 3.0},
 17: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.0},
 18: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.0},
 19: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.0},
 20: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.0},
 21: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.0},
 22: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.0},
 23: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.0},
 24: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.0},
 25: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.0},
 26: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.1622776601683795},
 27: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.1622776601683795},
 28: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.1622776601683795},
 29: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.1622776601683795},
 30: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.1622776601683795},
 31: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.1622776601683795},
 32: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.1622776601683795},
 33: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 34: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 35: {0: 3.1622776601683795, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 36: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 37: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 38: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 39: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 40: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 41: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 42: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 43: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 44: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 45: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 46: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 47: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 48: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 49: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 50: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 51: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 52: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 53: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 54: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 55: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 56: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 57: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 58: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 59: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 60: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 61: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 62: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 63: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 64: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 65: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 66: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 67: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 68: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 69: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 70: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 71: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 72: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 73: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 74: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 75: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 76: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 77: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 78: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 79: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 80: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 81: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 82: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 83: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 84: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 85: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 86: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 87: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 88: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 89: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 90: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 91: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 92: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 93: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 94: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 95: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 96: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 97: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 98: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554},
 99: {0: 3.3166247903554, 1: 3.3166247903554}}
```

I have a list of list with different lengths which contains the index of columns which I need.

```
list_idx = [[array([ 7, 12, 49])], [array([ 4, 34, 41, 45, 80, 82])]]
```

The first element of list_idx ***([array([ 7, 12, 49])])*** is values ​​to extract for the first row. 
           **<->**
*Row 1 :I need the value of 7th, 12th and 49th columns of my dataframe.*

Here the code to do this, but is there a faster way to extract values?

```
finalListofList=[
for (row,idx) in zip(df.iterrows(),list_idx ):
   finalListofList.append(list(row[1][idx[0]]))
```

Comment: finalListofList is a list of list. 
The first element of finalListofList will be the values of 6, 11, 48 df's columns.
The second elements will be the values 3, 33, 40, 44, 79, 81 df's columns ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy indexing in list comprehension:

```
finalListofList = [row[idx[0]].tolist() for row, idx in zip(df.values, list_idx)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
finalListofList = df.loc[0,list_idx[0][0]].values
# array([3.        , 3.        , 3.31662479])
```

Note that the extra `[0]` in `list_idx[0][0]`is because you have a nested list, i.e. `list_idx[0]` still gives a list which is not valid to index in this case.

You can read more about indexing and selecting data [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

Comment: How to convert list of tuples (list_idx created with np.where() list comprehension) to list of list ? 
I would like list_idx = [[7, 12, 49], [4, 34, 41, 45, 80, 82]]. 
What is the advantage of this format [[array([ 7, 12, 49])], [array([ 4, 34, 41, 45, 80, 82])]] ?

Comment: `[i.tolist() for i in a]`

Comment: Thanks @yatu in my case : [list(i) for i in a] produces [[array([ 7, 12, 49])], [array([ 4, 34, 41, 45, 80, 82])]]. Is there a way to suppress the extra [0] to access the first element like this list_idx[0] will return [ 7 12 49] instead of [array([ 7, 12, 49])] ?

Comment: Share a sample of `a`

Comment: a is list_idx corresponding to [(array([ 7, 12, 49]),), (array([ 4, 34, 41, 45, 80, 82]),)]

Comment: Do `[list(i[0]) for i in s]`